# Capitalize list of tables in Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, capitalization

How can I capitalize all the table names in the Table of Contents, List of Tables? 
I am not talking about the headings, but the actual entries. E.g., the first entry in the picture is ok, as it is uppercase, while the others are not.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the optional arguments to `\caption` and/or `\section`.  EDITED to follow egreg's emphatic recommendation.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\noindent\hrulefill

\section[\MakeUppercase{this is the first of two sections}]{this is the first of two sections}

\lipsum[4]

\section[\MakeUppercase{blah for blah}]{blah for blah}

\lipsum[3]

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption[\MakeUppercase{this is the table for this section}]{this is the table for this section}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
This is & my table\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Based on a follow-up query by the OP, here is a way to get just the LOT (but not the LOF) to automatically capitalize the table captions:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\let\svcaption\caption
\let\svtable\table
\def\table{\tablecaps\svtable}
\def\tablecaps{%
  \renewcommand\caption[2][]{\svcaption[\MakeUppercase{##2}]{##2}}
}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\noindent\hrulefill
\section{blah for blah}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\framebox{My Figure}
\caption{this is the figure caption}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{this is the table for this section}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
This is & my table\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That works, thank you for your answer, but I would prefer not to modify every single entry in the document. Is that possible?

Comment: @Edo In the preamble, `\renewcommand\caption[2][]{\svcaption[\uppercase{#2}]{#2}}` will ignore any optional argument in `\caption` (both tables and figures) and use the uppercase equivalent of the 2nd argument as the LOT/LOF entry.  Does that suffice?

Comment: The command to use is *definitely* `\MakeUppercase`, not `\uppercase`.

Comment: @egreg  Thanks.  Revised, though I'll have to search for the nuanced reason why.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Try with `\'i` in the caption text.

Comment: @egreg I tried some normal umlauts with success, but hadn't stumbled upon that one yet.  Thanks for the lesson.

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear if you want all material in table of contents and list of tables and figures to be uppercase (which is bad style, I'd say).

Here's a set of patches for the `article` class. If you're using `book` or `report` also the chapter title commands should be patched.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@caption}
  {\ignorespaces #2}
  {\MakeUppercase{\ignorespaces #2}}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\@sect}{\fi#7}{\fi\MakeUppercase{#7}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@sect}{\fi#7}{\fi\MakeUppercase{#7}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables

\section{Title}

\subsection{Title}

\lipsum[3]

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{This is a table caption}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
This is & my table\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption[Optional]{This is a table caption}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
This is & my table\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @egreg, I know this style is very unpleasant, but it is mandatory to have the thesis accepted by a US university.

Comment: @Edo Please, let me know if you need also uppercase chapter titles, also telling what document class you're using.

Comment: thanks a lot, submitted and accepted. It was a custom class by the university, a real nightmare :)

Comment: @Edo You have all my sympathy. ;-)